# Twilio: Android Error TwilioConversations [Signaling]

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-api

I have a problem when call ends, and `finish()` to current activity of conversation, app blows me, but does not show me any error, and often appears me this error:

```
E/TwilioConversations: [Signaling]:RESIP::TRANSPORT: Got TLS read ret=0 error=6 error:00000006:invalid library (0):OPENSSL_internal:public key routines
```

If someone could help me because I have a lot of time with this problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question so the community can review it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other 3rd-party libraries that use SSL? There may be a conflict between the [Twilio Video SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android) and another library.

I have also seen this resolved by ensuring that you have the [latest version of the SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/changelogs/android) installed.

However, if you can let me know any more specifics regarding your code, I'm happy to help debug further.